# Try install rest in codeigniter 3 by composer

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter-3

I know that my controller no find the instalation..so, whtat I have to do to included it??

#### First step:

So I run composer in my CI this github :https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-rest

#### Second step:

this project was install in /vendor/yidas/codeigniter-rest/

#### Third step

I created my controller like this :

```
class Rest_api extends yidas\rest\Controller {}
```

#### last:

I receve this error:

```
Message: Class 'yidas\rest\Controller' not found
Filename: /var/www/html/realmoney/application/controllers/Rest_api.php

Backtrace:
File: /var/www/html/realmoney/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue at the beginning, but then I realized that I was installing it wrongly.

This happened to me:

When I run `composer require yidas/codeigniter-rest` in application folder, I got these question:

> No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3path? [Y,n]? n

I answered "Y", but I should have answered "n". This way, it will create a vendor folder in application, and not in ci3path.

After this, I just create a controller like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use yidas\rest\Controller;

class Resource extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      return $this->response->json(['bar' => 'foo']);
   }
}
```

Now it works.